Why does Jay Chou pronounce "拓" incorrectly in Lan Ting Xu?
In the song Lan Ting Xu by Jay Chou it features the line:

忙不迭 千年碑易拓卻難拓妳的美

Here 拓 should, by all acounts, be read 「ta」in the context. Yet, in the song he can be heard reading it as「tuo」almost twice in a row. It can be heard in his music video at about 0:42.
At first I just assumed this was a Guoyu variant pronunciation. But, looking at MoE Dict and Liang'an, this does not seem to be the case.
Perhaps he just didn't know what Vincent Fang meant.
Ideas?

I think most people, as well as him and the lyric writer, know that 拓 should be pronounced as 「ta」here,  but it does not rhyme well with the rest of the lyric, so they decided to go for the other pronunciation of 拓 instead.

Pop music may be open-minded about correct pronunciation, but Jay Chou aka 周董 is super serious in Chinese culture and producing Chinese cultural music. He do speak wrong of 拓 in the MV version (as posted by @Mou某), but corrected it since then, thanks to the supervision of grand amount of his fans :-D. You can hear him singing correctly in the Live version on a much important stage.
By the way he also seems to speak wrong of the word 藤蔓植物 in 威廉古堡 both in the MV and the Live. Even me hadn't noticed it since writing this answer. Ref 周杰伦音乐发音错误大盘点, 藤蔓一词的读音是否经历过更改？
Another similar and famous example of wrong word singing is

羽扇纶巾谈笑间强虏灰飞烟灭 --念奴娇, 伊能静, 2006

where she spoke 纶 as 抡 in the MV version, but corrected it quickly in following performances to prevent being criticized.
The interesting but not firm connection is that the 念奴娇 is song composed by Jay Chou. The lyric is not although.

拓展的发音是【tuo zhan】
一个字在不同的语境中可以有不同的发音，详情见关于卒的介绍 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/59190/36261
如果你打算通过听周杰伦的歌来练习中文听力，我只能说你是走在错误的道路上，如果你想练习中文听力，应该通过听中国官方媒体主持人的发音，比如CCTV，中文国际等，这些播音主持人的发音很标准
凡是你听到周杰伦歌曲的发音和普通话不一致，都是周杰伦自己发音的问题。
周杰伦唱歌有一个很大的特定：吐字不清，如果你不理解吐字不清是什么意思的话，可以理解为发音有问题，说的不是普通话。
周杰伦的歌曲当作娱乐，听听就好，不必较真。
关于周杰伦吐字不清的吐槽见下面的链接:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8mGJqoQZ4s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8ECB50Z2r8 这个视频44分钟，觉得视频时间长的话，看看视频标题就好。
https://www.guancha.cn/politics/2019_05_12_501263.shtml  这个链接里面的内容看下面的截图


In Taiwan, we usually pronounce it as ㄊㄨㄛˋ in 拓印， though it's incorrect.
If you've ever visited Taiwan, you'll notice that we do not really care for the pronunciation of some words (as long as one's not a Mandarin teacher).

请问中国大陆人可以申请加入台湾国籍吗？如果可以的话，有什么途径吗？

我是真的考虑离开中国了，见我的观点 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/59181/36261

@Tom 目前找到的方法好像只有移民歸化

好的，感谢回复。在移民歸化中，移民什么化，哪个字我不认识。

@Tom 那個詞用檢體寫是「归化」

好的，感谢告知，我在网上查查相关资料。
